# WebDirect - grab active URL and return to Filemaker field?

Tags: filemaker

I have a WebDirect solution, upon where the user can select items of clothing from our website. I had this working perfectly when testing in FM Pro Adv, but doesnt work on the WebDirect.

Basically, I have 1 main web viewer which takes the user to our clothes website, using this webviewer the user must browse item they would like, and when on the correct item, they hit a little button on the WebDirect solution which basically pull off the URL of the item in the webviewer, and copies this into a FileMaker field.

Now as I said, this works flawlessly within FileMaker, but not WebDirect, as many people say this cannot be achieved using GetLayoutObjectAttribute (source)
in WebDirect (which I am using)

So my question is, what other ways could this be achieved, which will also work within a WebDirect?

Thanks in advance x

Comment: When you say "pull off the URL of the item in the webviewer" you need to describe in more details how it is done. FileMaker Script editor can show you which scripts are not compatible with webdirect. If you use fmp:// url format - it will not trigger your browser client

Comment: Nicolai I think you're misunderstanding my issue. GetLayoutObjectAttribute works in WebDirect. Just not the function I need, I'm currently using GetLayoutObjectAttribute ( "webviewer" ; "source" )

Which I have set up so that it will copy the url of the page currently displayed in the WebViewer into a FileMaker field. However the documentation states that "source" and "content" will return a blank value when used in WebDirect, so my issue is that I need another way to get this URL. I hope that is clear enough? Its a simple thing I need to do, just having issues achieving it. Any advice?

Comment: OK, I understand it now. It will not work this way and I do not think there is an easy solution. If you have control over your clothing site you can try adding the code there to call FileMaker data api or xml API to set the field in the record.